# No nowhere vanishing section of the canonical complex line bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology

Milnor and Stasheff, problem 13-E:

Let $\pi:E\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$ be the tautological bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^n$, prove that it has no nowhere vanishing holomorphic section, however its dual bundle $Hom_\mathbb{C}(\pi,\mathbb{C})$ has at least $n+1$ holomorphic sections that are linear independent over $\mathbb{C}$.

Here is my attempt: if we have a holomorphic (actually continuous) section of $\pi:\mathbb{C}P^n\rightarrow E$ that is nowhere vanishing, then we get a map $f:S^{2n+1}\rightarrow E$ by precomposing it with the canonical map $S^{2n+1}\rightarrow E$. This map satisfies $f(v)$ is a scalar multiple of $v$ and $f(\alpha v)=f(v)$ if $\alpha$ is a complex number of norm 1. Hence there is a function $g:S^{2n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}-0$ such that $f(v)=g(v)v$. We then have $g(\alpha v)=g(v)/\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ of unit norm. This actually means that $g$ maps the loop $\alpha v, |\alpha|=1$ to a nontrivial loop in $\mathbb{C}-0$.   This is impossible since the fundamental group of $S^{2n+1}$ is trivial.

As for the second part, take the standard basis $e_1,...,e_{n+1}$ of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, then $n+1$ sections of the dual bundle is given by the coordinate functions of this basis.

Is my solution correct? I feel like I'm not using the condition being holomorphic in the first part. Thanks!

Comment: You are not in fact using anything holomorphic in the first part. That's fine. The bundle has no continuous section. In the second part, you will get an infinite-dimensional space of smooth (or continuous) sections, but a finite-dimensional space of holomorphic sections. (You have not proved that, of course. But it's true.)

Comment: In case it's of interest, there's a separate proof for the first part that _does_ use "holomorphic": $E$ is by construction a holomorphic subbundle of $\mathbf{CP}^{n}\times\mathbf{C}^{n+1}$. A holomorphic section of $E$ induces (by projection to the second factor) a holomorphic map $\mathbf{CP}^{n}\to\mathbf{C}^{n+1}$. Since projective space is compact, this map is constant by the maximum principle. Since the constant value lies in every line through the origin (by construction of the tautological bundle), its value is $0$.

Comment: I am confused, how can there be cross sections of the dual bundle but not the original bundle? Don't we obtain the original bundle by the conjugate of the dual bundle, so if the dual has a cross section this implies the original line bundle is trivial.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Note that a smooth real line bundle may have non-zero sections without being trivial (e.g., the Moebius strip projected to its central circle). The intuition for holomorphic bundles and sections has additional distinctive features from the smooth case. For example: 1. A holomorphic line bundle and its dual are not generally isomorphic as holomorphic bundles; generally (as is the case here) they do not even have the same first Chern class. Conjugation is not holomorphic, so metrics are no help. 2. A holomorphic bundle can be smoothly trivial but holomorphically non-trivial. (!)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I take cross section (which is the term Milnor-Stasheff use) to mean a nowhere zero section. It is the case that a line bundle which has a cross section is trivial (interpret the value of the section as the image of $1$ of the vector bundle $X \times \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @ConnorMalin: I don't have Milnor-Stasheff at hand, but "non-vanishing" is not the sense in which _section_ is being used in this question (despite the exercise apparently coming from M-S). The dual of the tautological bundle over complex projective space does even not have non-vanishing _continuous_ sections (as Ted notes), but it does have holomorphic sections other than the zero section. <> If that doesn't clarify, I think we're talking at cross-purposes (as it were).